# How can I create a stand alone .NET client which calls a web service secured with OAuth?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4

I need to write a stand alone (command line) program which calls a web service which uses OAuth 2 for authentication. The web service use IndentityServer4. I am looking for a library which I can use for this and some sample code.

I am new to OAuth so do not understand all the ins and outs of the protocol but I was able to get a token using postman, by supplying these paramers. I guess the Auth URL is the address of the login screen.

Auth URL, Access Token URL, ClientID, Client Secret and Scope.

When I request a token Postman goes to a login page implemented by the server implementing OAuth, where I need to type in a separate user name and password.

If my understanding is correct, for this to work we need to make a change to the server to allow non interactive login by somehow passing the application user name an password.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1185880/ASP-NET-Core-WebAPI-secured-using-OAuth-Client-Cre

Comment: The common oauth flow is designed for browsers, not client apps. Look at a Jwt Bearer & webapi flow for a client app.

Comment: @Tracher - The back end we have created is designed to serve a front end web app so having a login page makes sense, but we also want to have a non interactive client for testing purposes. Is possible to design OAuth workflows that work both interactively and non interactively? We rather not introduce a second authentication method if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The [IdentityModel nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/) has clients and helpers to simplify requesting (and using) access tokens from the IdentityServer. You can find info about the library on its [github page](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2). There are some good examples of how to obtain tokens and use them to call a web API in the IdentityServer4 quickstarts:

[Protecting an API using client credentials](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html)

[Protecting an API using passwords](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html)

Here's an example using client credentials to get a token and then calling the api with the token:

```
// discover the token endpoint
var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://identityserver");

// request an access token
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");
var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("your-api");

// call the api
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

var response = await client.GetAsync("http://yourapi/some-resource");
```

Comment: this looks promising. At the moment we need to go through a login screen screen implemented by the server (have modified my question). I think we need to configure Identity server on the server side to allow non interactive authentication, do you know how we would then use IdentityModel to authenticate?

Comment: My mistake - I mis-read your question. I missed the part about OAuth and assumed you were using the Jwt Bearer middleware to authenticate your API, as that's the typical approach.